# incompatible types found : java.lang.String

Tags: java, switch-statement, javac

I'm learning java and I wrote this program and it compiled successfully on my college computer but not compiling on my home pc.can any one help me?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator{

    public static void main(String[] args){
    
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Please Enter 2 Values");
        
        int userInput1 = input.nextInt();
        int userInput2 = input.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("Please Enter an Operation");
        
        String operator = input.next();
        if(operator == null){
            return;
        }
        
        int answer = 0;
        
        switch (operator){
            case "+":
                answer = Add(userInput1,userInput2);    
            break;
            case "*":
                answer = Multiply(userInput1,userInput2);       
            break;          
            case "-":
                answer = Subtract(userInput1,userInput2);       
            break;          
            case "/":
                answer = Divide(userInput1,userInput2);     
            break;          
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Operator");
                System.exit(0);
            break;
        }
        
    
        System.out.println("The answer is " + answer);
        
    }

    public static int Add(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return num1 + num2;
    }
    
    
    public static int Subtract(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return num1 - num2;
    }

    public static int Multiply(int num1, int num2)
    {   
        return num1 * num2;
    }

    
    public static int Divide(int num1, int num2)
    {   
        return num1 / num2;
    }
    
    
    
    
}
```

This is the error I'm getting :

> Calculator.java:23: incompatible types
>
> found   : java.lang.String
>
> required: int
>
> ```
>            switch (operator){
>
>                    ^
> ```
>
> 1 error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `switch` on a `String` was introduced in Java 7. Make sure you're using JDK7+ on the other machine to compile the program.

As mentioned in the comments, if you can't upgrade the JDK for some reason, you can use a `char` instead:

```
String operator = input.next();
if(operator == null || operator.isEmpty()) {
   return;
}
int answer = 0;
switch (operator.charAt(0)) {
    case '+':
        answer = Add(userInput1, userInput2);
        break;
    case '*':
        answer = Multiply(userInput1, userInput2);
        break;
    ...
```

Comment: is there anyway I can use this on my current java version?

Comment: I'm using jdk1.6.0_25

Comment: @CoderMax: Not with strings, you'd have to change the code to use `char` instead (it can, as all the strings used in the `switch` are one character long). But why would you want to? You clearly have access to the 'net, and the latest JDK is available for free. So download it and use it.

Comment: If you need a quick solution use switch(operator.hashCode()). (And of course "*".hashCode() in every case )

Comment: seems like there is no other way than to use Java 7.

downloading it now.

Comment: There are other ways to solve this particular problem.  But you'll continue running into trouble if you have Java 7 at college and Java 6 at home.  You have made the right decision.